# Wrong record selected when datatable is filtered

Tags: primefaces

I have one problem that needs to be resolve asap and would need you guys help here.
I have a datatable with selectBooleanCheckbox and column filtering and a Delete button (ajax="false"). When the page load, I have five records in this order, Record 1, Record 2, Record 3, Record 4, Record 5. After that, I filter for 3. Then I check the checkbox and click on Delete. But Record 1 got deleted instead.

Thanks on advance!

```
<td><p:commandButton ajax="false" type="submit"
            value="#{msg.rq1001_command_delete}" styleClass="commandButton"
            id="rq1001_command_delete"
            action="#{pc_Rq1001.doRq1001_command_deleteAction}"></p:commandButton>
     </td>

     <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr valign="top">
              <td valign="top" width="760"><p:dataTable
                    styleClass="dataTable" id="rq1001_datatable_request"
                    value="#{pc_Rq1001.w_request.listrequest}" var="varlistrequest"
                    rows="50" paginator="true"
                    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
                    {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 25, 50, 75,100,200"
                    resizableColumns="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                    filteredValue="#{pc_Rq1001.w_request.listOfFilteredRequest}">

                    <p:column id="column1" width="20">
                       <f:facet name="header">
                       </f:facet>
                       <p:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="selectBooleanCheckbox"
                          id="rq1001_checkbox_select" value="#{varlistrequest.select}"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column3" width="40" resizable="true"
                       sortBy="#{varlistrequest.approved_sn}"
                       style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                       headerText="#{msg.rq1001_gridheader_approved}">
                       <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText" id="text3"
                          value="#{varlistrequest.approved_sn}"></h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column_ID" width="80"
                       sortBy="#{varlistrequest.requesttradeid}"
                       filterBy="#{varlistrequest.requesttradeid}"
                       filterMatchMode="contains" resizable="true"
                       filterStyle="width:70px"
                       style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                       headerText="#{msg.rq1001_gridheader_reqtradeid}" 
                       filterValue="#{varlistrequest.fv_requesttradeid}">
                       <p:commandLink ajax="false" styleClass="commandLink"
                          id="rq1001_commandlink_requestid" 
                          action="#{pc_Rq1001.doRq1001_commandlink_requestidAction}">
                          <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText_px"
                             id="rq1001_gridoutput_reqid"
                             value="#{varlistrequest.requesttradeid}"></h:outputText>

                          <f:param name="clicked_requestid"
                             value="#{varlistrequest.requestid}"></f:param>
                       </p:commandLink>

                       <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="column2" width="80"
                       sortBy="#{varlistrequest.acctcntr_sn}"
                       filterBy="#{varlistrequest.acctcntr_sn}"
                       filterMatchMode="contains" resizable="true"
                       filterStyle="width:70px"
                       style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                       headerText="#{msg.rq1001_gridheader_acctcntr}" 
                       filterValue="#{varlistrequest.fv_acctcntr_sn}">
                       <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText_px"
                          id="rq1001_output_acctcntr_sn"
                          value="#{varlistrequest.acctcntr_sn}"></h:outputText>
                       <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column5" width="60"
                       sortBy="#{varlistrequest.status_sn}"
                       filterBy="#{varlistrequest.status_sn}"
                       filterMatchMode="contains" resizable="true"
                       filterStyle="width:50px"
                       style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                       headerText="#{msg.rq1001_gridheader_status}" 
                       filterValue="#{varlistrequest.fv_status_sn}">
                       <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText_px" id="text1"
                          value="#{varlistrequest.status_sn}"></h:outputText>
                       <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column7" width="80"
                       sortBy="#{varlistrequest.reqdate}"
                       filterBy="#{varlistrequest.reqdate}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                       resizable="true" filterStyle="width:70px"
                       style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                       headerText="#{msg.rq1001_gridheader_reqdate}" 
                       filterValue="#{varlistrequest.fv_reqdate}">
                       <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText_px" id="text7"
                          value="#{varlistrequest.reqdate}">
                          <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{msg.i18n_date_format}" />
                       </h:outputText>
                       <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column4" width="200"
                       sortBy="#{varlistrequest.reqdescription}"
                       filterBy="#{varlistrequest.reqdescription}"
                       filterMatchMode="contains" resizable="true"
                       filterStyle="width:190px"
                       style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                       headerText="#{msg.rq1001_gridheader_description}" 
                       filterValue="#{varlistrequest.fv_reqdescription}">
                       <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText_px" id="text2"
                          value="#{varlistrequest.reqdescription}"></h:outputText>
                       <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column8" width="200"
                       sortBy="#{varlistrequest.done_description}"
                       filterBy="#{varlistrequest.done_description}"
                       filterMatchMode="contains" resizable="true"
                       filterStyle="width:190px"
                       style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                       headerText="#{msg.rq1001_gridheader_contract_details}" 
                       filterValue="#{varlistrequest.fv_done_description}">
                       <p:commandLink ajax="false" styleClass="commandLink"
                          id="rq1001_commandlink_done_description" 
                          action="#{pc_Rq1001.doRq1001_commandlink_done_descriptionAction}">
                          <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText_px"
                             id="rq1001_output_contract_details"
                             value="#{varlistrequest.done_description}"></h:outputText>
                          <f:param name="clicked_done_requestid"
                             value="#{varlistrequest.requestid}"></f:param>
                       </p:commandLink>
                       <p:commandLink ajax="false" styleClass="commandLink"
                          id="rq1001_commandlink_process" 
                          action="#{pc_Rq1001.doRp1001_commandlink_processAction}">
                          <h:outputText id="text5" styleClass="outputGridText_px"
                             rendered="#{varlistrequest.processable}"
                             value="#{msg.rp1001_output_process}"
                             style="background-color: #0000a0; color: white"></h:outputText>
                          <f:param name="process_requestid"
                             value="#{varlistrequest.requestid}"></f:param>
                       </p:commandLink>
                       <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                    </p:column>
                 </p:dataTable>
              </td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>

       public String doRq1001_command_deleteAction() {
  String _LOC = "[doRq1001_command_deleteAction]";
  // System.out.println(_LOC + "1.0");

  if (_w.getListrequest() != null) {
     for (Iterator iter = _w.getListrequest().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        W_request _wr = (W_request) iter.next();
        if (_wr.isSelect()) {
           _no_selected = false;
           if (_wr.getStatus().equals(ORDER_STATUS_PROCESSED)
                 || _wr.getStatus().equals(ORDER_STATUS_LOCKED)) {
              _delete_locked_processed = true;
           } else {
              _w.deleteRequest(_wr.getRequestid());
           }
        }
     }
  } else {
     showCommonMessage_ByKey("rq1001_message_refresh_list");
     return null;
  }

  if (_no_selected) {
     showCommonMessage_ByKey("rq1001_message_delete_no_select");
     return null;
  } else {
     _w.populateRequest();
  }

  if (_delete_locked_processed) {
     showCommonMessage_ByKey("rq1001_message_delete_not_open_locked");
  }

  return "";
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use the Primefaces select (single and multiple) build-in function instead.

basic

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf

single

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf

multiple

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf

instant

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf

Radio/checkbox (i think this is one solution for your problem)

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf